# what mistake am I making in this simple wpf app loop in c Sharp?

Tags: c#, wpf, loops

I am trying to develop a very simple and tiny little coding language just as a fun side project. The issue I am currently facing makes me feel stupid. See we have a label wherein the entire code is typed in the program and it is divided into lines of code with the help of String.Split() with a semicolon ';'. It all works till here but then when I try to split each line of code with a dot '.' to see if "print" is one of the elements(say j) and hence get the next element (j+1) added to the output Label Content String. Let me first show the code.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String[] lines = code.Text.Split(';');
        String labelContent = "";
        String[] dotSeperated = new string[] { };


        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length -1; i++)
        {
           dotSeperated = lines[i].Split('.');


            for (int j = 0; j < dotSeperated.Length; j++)
            {
                if(dotSeperated[j] == "print")
                {
                    labelContent += dotSeperated[j + 1];
                }
            }
        }


        

        lb.Content = labelContent;

    }
```

But when the program is run,

[Program Build Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peAhH.png)

which is that if I input
print.a;
print.b;

The output only says 'a' instead of 'ab'
Please help me as I can't at all figure out the solution. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `i < lines.Length -1` why the "-1"?

Comment: This sir is because the semicolon at the last line's end adds another element to the lines array which is empty.

Comment: This is just a simple side project sir and is not meant to be CLOSE to a real language. All I want to do with this is to test out my skills but yes its not turning out to be all that great and the reason I asked the question is also just because I wanna know where the problem exists. Thank you sir

Comment: You could use the debugger to see that the lines[i] contains a linebreak (\r\n") and thus `if(dotSeperated[j] == "print")` will not match.

Comment: Use `.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` so you don't have to do `.Length - 1`. You should also use `if(dotSeperated[j].Trim() == "print")` so that it removes whitespace (like newline characters).

Comment: How then sir does it work with the first line??

Comment: Thanks Daevin. Let me just try that out...

Comment: Please don't assume everyone here is male

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output says only 'a' because input string have new line symbol between "print.a;" and "print.b;"

The condition `if(dotSeperated[j] == "print")` is not satisfied and only 'a' is printed.

Try to change 1st line of code like `String[] lines = code.Text.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Split(';');`

Comment: Whar about `\r`?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes. 1st line should be like.  ```String[] lines = code.Text.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Split(';');```

Comment: Thanks a lot to Daevin and Vladimir D. for being helpul. I have got your point and you have solved my problem so thanks a tonne.

Comment: Good catch @VladimirD., a cleaner option may be to use the [SpiltOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-6.0) parameter of the `Split` function to remove the empty line results, e.g. `String[] lines = code.Text.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`.

Comment: @quaabaam Yes, you're right. Your variant is cleaner.